# Microservices sharing a database acrossed multiple services

Tags: database, microservices

Say I have a weather database for sports; football, soccer, college football, baseball etc..

I want to be able to share that single "weather" database acrossed each sport, since each latitude and longitude is different, I put all the locations in my weather database but each sport is its' own database. How would you connect all those sports to the weather database, while keeping each sport in its own database in a microservice architecture?

does anyone have any good information on this kind of sharing architecture?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Certain questions here are more likely to get helpful answers. Questions that don’t show what you’ve tried are generally more difficult to answer - people often skip right over them. So show your code for best results. If you encounter a specific technical problem during that attempt, we can help with that, and we want to - that’s part of why we’re here. To learn more about helping us help you, please start with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask). If you’re really ambitious, read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing a database between multiple services in a micro-services architecture is an anti-pattern.

My suggestions are:

- In case your weather needs are supplied by mainly using a 3rd party API to some weather service, you might want to go with a shared library that wraps this API and supplies each of your services the information in the relevant sport related adaptation you need. Also you might incorporate a caching layer for this information.
- In case you have more elaborate domain logic around your weather needs you might want to address your weather as a domain of its own with a dedicated service using a dedicated database for storing these weather information, having your other sports related services communicate with it.